# calling system() from c

Tags: c, system

I was trying to execute system calls from c. When the following code is executed, the date is printed first followed by   `" Todays date is ..........:"` on a new line. When I replaced `printf` by puts, it executed as I intended.(the `objdump` showed *puts@plt* in place of the second `printf`). Can anybody tell me why it is so?

```
  #include <stdlib.h>

    int main() { printf(" Todays date is ..........:");

    system("/bin/date");
    printf("\n This is your exclusive shell\n");  
    system("/bin/sh");
    return 0; 
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printf()` put your string in a buffer, and once you go down a line it write it to the screen. that's why when you do

```
printf(" Todays date is ..........:");

system("/bin/date");
```

You might get the date printed first.

The `stdout` stream is buffered, so will only display what's in the buffer after it reaches a newline (or when it's told to). You have a few options to print immediately:

- Print to `stderr` instead using `fprintf`:

  ```
  fprintf(stderr, "I will be printed immediately");
  ```
- Flush `stdout` whenever you need it to using `fflush`:

  ```
  printf("Buffered, will be flushed");
  fflush(stdout); // Will now print everything in the stdout buffer
  ```
- or you can also disable buffering on `stdout` by using `setbuf`:

  ```
  setbuf(stdout, NULL);
  ```

Comment: Suppose if OP adds `\n` in first `printf("Today......\n")`  then he should get uniform behavior, because `\n` force to `fflush`. Am I correct?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan it does not work on my system. but all other suggestions work

Comment: @user146297 Thanks for informing. Though  NoIdeaForName's answer perfectly clears what happened and how to resolve. I think `\n` fflush is implementation defined if I get any link then I will share with you.

Comment: It depends if the stream is fully buffered (_IOFBF) or line buffered (_IOLBF). The standard does not state anything about how stdout should behave. But usually it is defaultly set to line buffered (or even unbuffered) in interactives modes.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf(" Todays date is ..........:");
```

==>

```
printf(" Todays date is ..........:\n");
```

Or add a `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` line;

Comment: `\n` always fflush in C **?** , because [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n) says it doesn't

Comment: I believe it flushes if stdout is connected to a line-buffered terminal, but it is implementation- (and system-) dependent.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan In line buffer `\n` flush the buffer. Terminal is line buffer by default

Comment: @LidongGuo that I also observe in past. But is it well defined behavior in C?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No , just some kind if easy way.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No, it's not specified in the C standard. It may be defined in POSIX, though. This is one of those cases where it crucially depends on what stdout actuall means ("stdout" is, I believe, well-defined as SOMETHING  in a C program compiled in a hosted environment, but it could be a regular file, a terminal or even network I/O and if the newline `printf("foo\n")` flushes or not is outside the scope of the C standard (and it probably does different things under Unix, Windows or VMS anyway).

Answer (score 2):

`printf` use a buffer.
If you want to print the text immediately you have to call `fflush`

```
printf(" Todays date is ..........:");
fflush(stdout);
system("/bin/date");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  #include <stdlib.h>  
  #include <stdio.h>

    int main() { printf(" Todays date is ..........:\n"); //add \n at the end. this is same behavior as puts. now date will print after this

    system("/bin/date");
    printf("\n This is your exclusive shell\n");  
    system("/bin/sh");
    return 0; 
    }
```

or else you can use `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("Todays date is ....:");` statement